# How to observe the changes made in Remote sql database table from android

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, synchronization

Currently am developing an android application in which i wish to intregrate the webservices and save the received datas in my sqlite database.Further if there is any changes in my remmote sql i wish to update the same thing in my sqlite too.How can i acheive this..is there any way to acheive this.I just stuck in this thing for more than 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options to perform the task:

You can ping the server for updates, for example if you upon starting call some API method getItems and store the items on local database, you can after certain interval call getItems again and replace the old items with the new ones

You can use a service like [GCM (Google Cloud Messaging)](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) to archieve this so your server sends the updated items straight to your phone, but this really depends on the application you're using it on

Comment: @Matalamaki if we replace the old items with new ones then it will increase data usage of an device while retrieving datas from server at certain period.how can i acheive this one with reduced data usage.

Comment: Then you'll need to keep track in your server which data you've already sent, but it should be more efficient to send some extra data and bare with it